# In VBA/Excel, how do I use ActiveX Option Buttons to change the linked cell of a drop down menu?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using Excel to create a sheet that will allow users to select a name from a drop down menu and output it to a particular cell. What I would like to do is use ActiveX Option Buttons to select the cell that the drop down menu will output to when used. So far, I've tried using the Option buttons to create a True/False flag in a cell that will be hidden next to the output cells, so that when an option is chosen from the drop down menu, it will output to whichever's cell indicator is set to True. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do this in VBA, or if there is a better way to do this, or if it's even possible at all.

The essence of my question: is it possible to use VBA controls to change the Linked Cell value of a drop down menu?

[image]

Comment: Weird, it's working for me. Is it an imgur error? I can mirror it somewhere else.

Comment: If you want something specific to happen every time the value in the dropdown changes, I would suggest not to have a linked cell, but to use the VBA `ComboBox1_Change` event procedure to do what you want with the new value in the dropdown.